# Delay response jumps

Tags: watson-conversation

What is the best way to show a user multiple responses?

Currently I have a few nodes that jump to another node without a condition to tigger a new response to show a new line of content to the user. The issue is that it all comes in the same time.

Is there a way to delay a response??

Comment: Can you provide the JSON file?

Comment: Have you find a way?

Answer (score 1):

The Watson Conversation service uses REST API to communicate with client application and responds "at once". This works in a way that the client request is processed via the defined dialog nodes tree and when this is finished everything is sent back to the client. 
If multiple nodes were hit then multiple responses can be returned to the client. If the client (implementing the chat console) wants to delay the answers this needs to be implemented on the client side.